# Use combination of digital certificates and symmetric key cryptography

Tags: encryption, certificates, cryptography, certificate-authority

Assuming that:
 
- A have CertA and secret key KsA 
 
- B have CertB and secret key KsB 

A need to transfer data M to B with the requirement of **confidentiality** and **authenticity**, **BUT** Data encryption must be done by **symmetric encryption**.

How do A and B do that to achieve all the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem a common solution is using a [Hybrid Cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Create a new random session key ([ephemeral key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48475/why-are-ephemeral-session-temporary-keys-useful)) for the symmetric encryption (AES) then encrypt the data with this key with a proper [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) with an appropriate [padding scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) as pkcs#5

```
key = generate_random_key()
encrypted_data = AES(k, data)
```

Now, A encrypts the session key with the B's public key.

```
encrypted_key = Encrypt(key, B_private_key)
```

Finally, A digitally sign everything

```
sign = Sign(Hash(encrypted_key || encrypted_data)
```

and send

```
Send(encrypted_data, encrypted_key, sign)
```

In this way;

- data encrypted with a **symmetric algorithm** which is much faster than asymmtrical encryption.
- data is **confidential** since encrypted with a key.
- data is **authenticated** since A uses his secret key to sign, and B can verify this with A's public certificate.

Comment: thank you so much, very straightforward and easy to understand !!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is how all [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) and [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) communications work.

2x Async certs/keys are used to create a shared secret which is used as a symmetric key for the lions share of the communication.

[image]

In step 6/7 of this diagram, is where the Symmetric key is created and both sides `ChangeCipherSpec` to make use of this newly established shared key.

Comment: thanks you so much, your answer is also very straightforward and give me lots of information :like: